# Relation between the coefficients of Virial expansion and fugacity expansion?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

This is a question that I posted in physics stackexchange, but I believe the problem is purely mathematical. Original question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/766989/relation-between-the-coefficients-of-virial-expansion-and-fugacity-expansion).

One can write pressure of an interacting dilute gas as an expansion in its fugacity $\xi = e^{\beta \mu}$ as,

$$\frac{P}{n_0T} = \sum_{l =1}^\infty b_{l} \xi^{l}$$

From this we can calculate the density as,
$$\frac{n}{n_0} = \sum_{l=1}^\infty l b_l \xi^l$$

On the other hand we have the virial expansion,
$$\frac{P}{nT} = \sum_{l=0}^\infty a_l \left(\frac{n}{n_0}\right)^{l-1}$$

$a_l$ and $b_l$ are related to each other which can be found from matching the above two relation in each order of fugacity. If one take $b_1 = 1$ then we have $a_1 = 1$, $a_2 = -b_2$, $a_3 = 2(2b_2^2 - b_3)$ and so on. Is there a simpler way to calculate this? For example is there a recursive formula to find the next coefficients from the previous one?